# Como usar left join fetch em CriteriaBuilder retornando um dto

Tags: java, criteria

na implementação abaixo, em que retorno um dto construido com a entidade Lancamento, em que esta possui relacionamento uni-direcional com categoria.
Para evitar o problema do n+1 tentei usar left join fetch entre Lancamento e categoria, das seguintes formas:

```
root.fetch("categoria", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Ou

```
Fetch<Lancamento, Categoria> categoriaFetch = root.fetch("categoria", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Nas duas situações acima, surgiu o mesmo erro:

```
"...query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias1,role=com.sisworks.sisbase.model.Lancamento.categoria,tableName=categoria,tableAlias=categoria1_,origin=lancamento lancamento0_,columns={lancamento0_.id_categoria,className=com.sisworks.sisbase.model.Categoria}}]"
```

Esta é a entidade Lancamento:

```
@Entity
public class Lancamento implements Serializable {

private OffsetDateTime dataVencimento;

private BigDecimal valor;

//uni-directional many-to-one association to Categoria
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_categoria", nullable=false)
private Categoria categoria;
```

Este é o método criteria:

```
public List<LancamentoEstatisticaCategoria> porCategoria(LocalDate mesReferencia) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<LancamentoEstatisticaCategoria> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder
            .createQuery(LancamentoEstatisticaCategoria.class);
    Root<Lancamento> root = criteriaQuery.from(Lancamento.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(LancamentoEstatisticaCategoria.class, 
            root.get(Lancamento_.categoria),
            criteriaBuilder.sum(root.get(Lancamento_.valor))));
    
    LocalDate primeiroDia = mesReferencia.withDayOfMonth(1);
    LocalDate ultimoDia = mesReferencia.withDayOfMonth(mesReferencia.lengthOfMonth());
    
    criteriaQuery.where(
            criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Lancamento_.dataVencimento),
                    primeiroDia),
            criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Lancamento_.dataVencimento),
                    ultimoDia));
    criteriaQuery.groupBy(root.get(Lancamento_.categoria));
    
    TypedQuery<LancamentoEstatisticaCategoria> typedQuery = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```